# Using a wildcard * to reference files in a directory

Tags: go

I'm trying to use this Go lang forum software https://github.com/kjk/fofou. It requires a config file in the top level forums directory to specify certain information about the forum (name, url etc). For example, the file that the software designer uses is `forums/sumatrapdf_config.json`

in main.go there is this function that reads forum config files

```
    func readForumConfigs(configDir string) error {
    pat := filepath.Join(configDir, "*_config.json")
    fmt.Println("path", pat)
    files, err := filepath.Glob(pat)
    fmt.Println("files", files, err)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if files == nil {
        return errors.New("No forums configured!")
    }
    for _, configFile := range files {
        var forum ForumConfig
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configFile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &forum)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !forum.Disabled {
            forums = append(forums, &forum)
        }
    }
    if len(forums) == 0 {
        return errors.New("All forums are disabled!")
    }
    return nil
}
```

I've played around with the second argument to the Join, calling it by the file name specifically and with the wildcard *, but I keep getting error messages telling me there are no files.

```
the log statements show the path that it's checking as well as the fact that no files are found
path forums/*funnyforum_config.json files [] 2014/07/25 10:34:11 Failed to read forum configs, err: No forums configured!
```

The same thing happens if I try to describe the config with a wildcard `*` as is done in the source code by the software creator

```
func readForumConfigs(configDir string) error { pat := filepath.Join(configDir, "*_config.json") fmt.Println("path", pat) files, err := filepath.Glob(pat) fmt.Println("files", files)

path forums/*_config.json files [] 2014/07/25 10:40:38 Failed to read forum configs, err: No forums configured!
```

In the forums directory, I have put various config files

```
funnyforum_config.json _config.json
```

as well as the config it came with

```
sumatrapdf_config.json
```

Comment: Did you check error returned from `Glob`?

Comment: @OneOfOne `fmt.Println("files", files, err)` shows `nil` for err

Comment: are you passing the full path to the directory? try that. out of curiosity, what version of go are you using?

Comment: @OneOfOne I'm using go 1.3. Regarding passing the full path, can you show me the code I should use to replace the first line of my function. Since I'd be passing the full path, I'd obviously not use Join but how to? pat := filepath.Join(configDir, "*_config.json")

Comment: What happens if you change `configDir` from `forums/` to `/complete/path/to/forums`.

Comment: @OneOfOne this is what I tried instead of configDir:   `path go/src/github.com/myname/fofou/*_config.json
files [] <nil>
2014/07/25 11:56:40 Failed to read forum configs, err: No forums configured!`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58019/discussion-between-oneofone-and-leahcim).

Comment: Leahcim: by **full path**, I believe folks are suggesting you to make sure you're using an **absolute path**, one that isn't relative to any particular current directory.  All the paths you've shown in the original question and responses have been relative, which looks very odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking the error from `glob`, you should, also you could implement it in a different way:

```
func FilterDirs(dir, suffix string) ([]string, error) {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    res := []string{}
    for _, f := range files {
        if !f.IsDir() && strings.HasSuffix(f.Name(), suffix) {
            res = append(res, filepath.Join(dir, f.Name()))
        }
    }
    return res, nil
}

func FilterDirsGlob(dir, suffix string) ([]string, error) {
    return filepath.Glob(filepath.Join(dir, suffix))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(FilterDirs("/tmp", ".json"))
    fmt.Println(FilterDirsGlob("/tmp", "*.json"))
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/9rcBwom_qK)

//edit

From our discussion, you have to either use a full path `/home/user/go/....../forums/` or a relative path `./forums/`.

Comment: I updated the OP with the whole function. Glob error is being checked and it's nil